# How to run bitbucket pipeline to deploy php based app on nanobox

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, nanoboxio

I am trying to setup bitbucket pipeline for a php based (Laravel-Lumen) app intended to be deployed on nanobox.io. I want this pipeline to deploy my app as soon as code changes are committed.

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like this

```
image: php:7.1.29

pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
    - step:
        name: Publish to staging version
        deployment: staging
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
#          - vendor/bin/phpunit
          - bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/tools.nanobox.io/bootstrap/ci.sh)"
          - nanobox deploy
```

This gives Following error

```
+ nanobox deploy
Failed to validate provider - missing docker - exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
Using nanobox with native requires tools that appear to not be available on your system.
docker
View these requirements at docs.nanobox.io/install
```

I then followed [this page](https://docs.nanobox.io/workflow/ci-cd/) and changed second last line to look like this

```
sudo bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/tools.nanobox.io/bootstrap/ci.sh)"
```

when done that, I am getting following error

```
+ sudo bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://s3.amazonaws.com/tools.nanobox.io/bootstrap/ci.sh)"
bash: sudo: command not found
```

I ran out of tricks here, also I don't have experience in this area. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use `sudo` in pipelines, but that's probably not relevant here. The issue is that nanobox cli wan't to execute docker, which isn't installed. You should enable the docker service for your step.

```
image: php:7.1.29

pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Publish to staging version
          deployment: staging

          # Enable docker service
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - docker version
```

You might wan't to have a look at Pipelines docs as well: [Run Docker commands in Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html)